# ADOQuery Get Result (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

I Tried to get result from ADOQuery in Delphi. I wrote this function for Get a Name from table according custom ID.

```
function GetNameByID(Id : Integer) : string;
var query : string;
  Begin
  ShowMessage(GetDBGridViewIndex().ToString);
  query := 'SELECT Name FROM Table1 WHERE ID=' + IntToStr(Id);
  With ADOQuery do
    Begin
       try
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add(query);
          Open;
          First;
          Result:= // Need Get Result;
       finally
          Close;
       end;
    End;
    
    ShowMessage(result);
End;
```

But I don't know how can return Result from ADOQuery.

Comment: ADOQuery has the result set. You can iterate if using  methods, properties and functions. Look at [TDataSet documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Navigating_Datasets) (TADOQuery is a TDataSet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TADOQuery` [is a descendant](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery) of `TDataset`.
You can iterate through the result records with the [First](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.First), [Next](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Next), [Prior](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Prior), and [Last](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Last) methods and find out if you've reached the end with [Eof](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof).

Within each result record you can access the fields with:

```
Fields[Index].AsString
Fields[Index].AsInteger
...
```

or

```
FieldByName(FieldName).AsString
FieldByName(FieldName).AsInteger
...
```

In this case you can access to the result using:

```
Result := Fields[0].AsString;
Result := FieldByName('Name').AsString;
```

After you `Open` the query, the cursor is pointing the First record. You don't need to call the `First` method after `Open`.